# Angularjs ui-grid filter items by checked/uncheck checkbox

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using ui-grid for testing purpose. I added a checkbox on each row and a select on header.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'uiGridConstants', function ($scope, uiGridConstants) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {
  enableFiltering: true,
  columnDefs: [
      {
        name: 'Items',
        filter: {
          type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
          selectOptions: [
            {value: '0', label: 'Unselect'},
            {value: '1', label: 'Selected'}
          ]
        },
        cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" name="select_item"/>'
      },
      {
        name: 'Name',
        field: 'name'
      },
      {
        name: 'Age',
        field: 'age'
      }
    ]
  };

  $scope.gridOptions.data = [
    { name: 'User 1', age: 20},
    { name: 'User 2', age: 30},
    { name: 'User 3', age: 40}
  ];
}]);
```

And this is the result

[image]

So how can I filter items by checked/uncheck checkbox? I only want to see all checked or unchecked items using filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the attribute selected to your data in order to be able to filter using the checkbox. You can delete it if you want to send data to the server.
modifications:

template:

```
  `cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" name="select_item" value="true" ng-model="row.entity.selected"/>`'
```

data:

```
  $scope.gridOptions.data = [
    { name: 'User 1', age: 20,selected:false},
    { name: 'User 2', age: 30,selected:false},
    { name: 'User 3', age: 40,selected:false}
  ];
```

here is a plunnker: [pluncker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zZbqIV2EMrGhaClMjn8Y?p=preview)

But,I recommand to use the selector of the ui-grid: [tutorial of ui-grid selector](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/210_selection)